# Perform arithmetic on a pointer returned using cudaMalloc() in host code

Tags: cuda

I am reading Cuda by examples book and I came across this sentence:

> However, it is the responsibility of the programmer not to dereference the pointer
>   returned by cudaMalloc() from code that executes on the host. Host code may
>   pass this pointer around, perform arithmetic on it, or even cast it to a different
>   type. But you cannot use it to read or write from memory.

Specifically, how would the 'perform an arithmetic on a pointer returned by cudaMalloc()' be done?

I tried running the following addition code with 2 additional lines before and after the kernel was called, but it had no effect on the output(which is 12 with or without those lines).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <device_launch_parameters.h>

__global__
void add(int a, int b, int *c)
{
    *c += a + b;
}

int main()
{
    int *c, d;
    cudaMalloc((void**)&c, sizeof(int));
    *c = 10;
    add << <1,1>> > (5,7,c);
    *c += 5;
    cudaMemcpy(&d, c, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    std::cout << d<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I am a beginner and wold appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[pointer arithmetic](https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/BitOp/pointer.html) is a concept associated with C and C++, it is not unique or specific to CUDA.

This is not an example of pointer arithmetic:

```
 *c = 10;
```

nor is this:

```
 *c += 5;
```

These are both modifications of what the pointer is pointing to, not the pointer itself.  Pointer arithmetic involves adjustments to the pointer value itself. (And by the way the code you have shown is illegal in CUDA - it is not legal to dereference ordinary device pointers in host code.  `*c` is an operation that *dereferences* the pointer `c`.  It is not the same as pointer arithmetic.)

Suppose I had a device memory allocation of 1024 `int` quantities:

```
cudaMalloc(&data, 1024 * sizeof(int));
```

Now suppose I wanted to cause the first invocation of a CUDA kernel to start working on the beginning of the array, and a second invocation of a CUDA kernel to start working at the midpoint of the array, but otherwise perform the same work.

I might do something like this, and the second kernel invocation has an argument that involves pointer arithmetic:

```
kernel<<<...>>>(data, 512);
kernel<<<...>>>(data+512, 512);
```

The `data+512` argument involves pointer arithmetic.  This will pass a pointer to the kernel that points to the midpoint of the data array, rather than the beginning of the array.  If I wanted to carry this pointer around in host code, I could do:

```
int *datahalf = data+512;
```

Comment: Explains perfectly. Thank you.